# How to get identity id type guid and assign to foreign key id in another table. Apply in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have used Fluent-API (EF Core in ASP.NET Core MVC) for my project to map code to database in SQL Server, but I am facing foreign key problem:

[image]

Please help me!

I have `LoaiDichVu` class and `LoaiDichVuConfiguration` class as follows:

```
public class LoaiDichVu
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string tenLoaiDichVu { get; set; }
    public string moTa { get; set; }
    public string trangThai { get; set; }

    public string fields1 { get; set; }
    public string fields2 { get; set; }
    public string fields3 { get; set; }
    public string fields4 { get; set; }
    public string fields5 { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DichVu> ICDichVu { get; set; }
}

public class LoaiDichVuConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<LoaiDichVu>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<LoaiDichVu> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("LoaiDichVu");
        builder.HasKey(ldv => ldv.ID);
        builder.Property(ldv => ldv.ID).HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()");
        builder.Property(ldv => ldv.tenLoaiDichVu).HasMaxLength(30);
        builder.Property(ldv => ldv.moTa).HasMaxLength(60);
        builder.Property(ldv => ldv.trangThai).HasMaxLength(30);
    }
}
```

And, I have `DichVu` and `DichVuConfiguration` class as follows:

```
public class DichVu
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid ID_LoaiDichVu { get; set; }
    public LoaiDichVu LoaiDichVu { get; set; }
    //Tên dịch vụ: Nước khoáng...
    public string tenDichVu { get; set; }
    //Đơn vị tính: Chiếc/ cái/ bao...
    public string donViTinh { get; set; }
    public decimal donGia { get; set; }
    //Đơn vị tính: VNĐ
    public string donViTien  { get; set; }
    public string moTa { get; set; }
    public string trangThai { get; set; }

    public string fields1 { get; set; }
    public string fields2 { get; set; }
    public string fields3 { get; set; }
    public string fields4 { get; set; }
    public string fields5 { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ChiTiet_HoaDon> ICChiTietHoaDon { get; set; }
}

public class DichVuConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<DichVu>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DichVu> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("DichVu");
        builder.HasKey(dv => dv.ID);
        builder.Property(dv => dv.ID).HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()");
        builder.Property(dv => dv.tenDichVu).HasMaxLength(50);
        builder.Property(dv => dv.donViTinh).HasMaxLength(20);
        builder.Property(dv => dv.donViTien).HasMaxLength(10);
        builder.Property(dv => dv.moTa).HasMaxLength(100);
        builder.Property(dv => dv.trangThai).HasMaxLength(30);
        builder.HasOne(dv => dv.LoaiDichVu).WithMany(dv => dv.ICDichVu).HasForeignKey(dv => dv.ID_LoaiDichVu).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
}
```

Then, I have a `ModelBuilderExtensions` class:

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void Seed(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<LoaiDichVu>().HasData(
                new LoaiDichVu() { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), tenLoaiDichVu = "Eat" }
               );
        modelBuilder.Entity<DichVu>().HasData(
                new DichVu() { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), ID_LoaiDichVu = Guid.NewGuid(),tenDichVu = "Rice", donGia = 99}
               );
    }
}
```

I have successfully added a migration.

If I set `ID_LoaiDichVu` as above, I get the following error:

[image]

I don't know how to get ID from `LoaiDichVu` table to assign to `ID_LoaiDichVu` in `DichVu` table

Please direct me how to assign by code instead of copy and assign

Example: `LoaiDichVu` (ID = 63763eb2-e537-4b97-a394-0529d216aa74)

And then assign

```
DichVu (ID = Guid.NewGuid(), ID_LoaiDichVu = 63763eb2-e537-4b97-a394-0529d216aa74)
```

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can **assign the value of Guid** to a **variable**, and then **assign it to ID** (LoaiDichVu) and **ID_LoaiDichVu** when initializing the data.

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void Seed(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var LoaiDichVuId = Guid.NewGuid();
        modelBuilder.Entity<LoaiDichVu>().HasData(
                new LoaiDichVu() { ID = LoaiDichVuId, tenLoaiDichVu = "Eat",  }
               );
        modelBuilder.Entity<DichVu>().HasData(
                new DichVu() { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), ID_LoaiDichVu = LoaiDichVuId, tenDichVu = "Rice", donGia = 99 }
               );
    }
}
```

[image]